# Message for my club members

Tags: cipher

Two people in particular have come to my Codes and Ciphers Club almost every week. One of them is always expecting a certain message to appear in the weekly puzzles, so of course I can't include it, unless I find a really clever way of disguising it so they won't be able to read it until they work out the rest of the puzzle. This is my attempt. This information is entirely irrelevant to solving the puzzle; it just makes sense of the solution.

I have included transcriptions below these images for your convenience. Note that the "cipher" tag, although it is the theme in my puzzles, is actually quite a small part of this puzzle.

Hints can be provided but I suspect it will be solved without them.

Credit: The image is taken from Seasons of Mystery: The Cherry Blossom Murders (video game)

[image]

[image]

```
-Left Column-
a.3-8-11/3-8-12
b.2-5-9/7-8
c.3-4-8/4-7-11
d.3-4-8/3-8-12
e.2-5-9/3-8-12
f.1-6-10/3-7-8
g.2-5-9/1-5-10
h.4-7-12/7-8
i.3-4-8/3-7-8
j.1-6-10/4-7-11
k.4-7-12/3-7-8
l.1-6-10/7-8
m.1-6-10/1-5-10
n.2-5-9/3-7-8
o.3-4-8/1-5-10
p.3-8-11/7-8
q.4-7-12/3-8-12
r.3-8-11/1-5-10
s.4-7-12/1-5-10
t.1-6-10/3-8-12
u.3-4-8/7-8
v.3-8-11/4-7-11
w.4-7-12/4-7-11
x.3-8-11/3-7-8
y.2-5-9/4-7-11
Joshua: UJXYSH
-Right Column-
H : VHKHKH
V : AWKRHKG
N : NYEATSKD
R : CEJFEK VJZ
W : AEAW
M : GHTVJSBEKW
O : XYBETA
Y : GYBWW
E : RBSTXGENDX
U : THAFW FWHM
D : YHGNYWG YHKRFW
F : WFD
T : NYWXX AEWNW
K : KWZXAHAWB
J : AENDHIW YWHR
A : NHG
P : AWKNEF
B : GWKKEX BHNDWG
X : YHGNYWG YWHR
G : NBJZK
S : GWRRL
C : XKHEF
Z : HNW JM REHTJKRX
I : GWKKEX VHFF
L : FHRLVSO
-Text along top of image (ignoring triangular symbols)-
CBVWHFIKTFSCFFEBAZZC
```

Hint:

> If we treat the left column as a list of pairs of number sets, there is the same number of unique numbers sets as there are unique triangular symbols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Right Column

> By mapping each rune to a letter that it looks similar to it (like the "Joshua" example), we get the following list of items:
>  1. banana
>  2. pendant
>  3. chipmunk
>  4. violin bow
>  5. pipe
>  6. tambourine
>  7. shrimp
>  8. three
>  9. drumsticks
>  10. maple leaf
>  11. hatchet handle
>  12. elk
>  13. chess piece
>  14. newspaper
>  15. pickaxe head
>  16. cat
>  17. pencil
>  18. tennis racket
>  19. hatchet head
>  20. crown
>  21. teddy
>  22. snail
>  23. ace of diamonds
>  24. tennis ball
>  25. ladybug

### Left Column:

> From the added hint from @Joshua Bizley, there is a correlation between the number "codes" (ie. X-Y-Z) and the triangular symbols. 7-8 is the only code with only two digits, and the top-right triangular symbol is the only one with two small triangles, so they must go together. This means the second code in a pair corresponds to the horizontal symbols. The symbol to its left adds a small triangle, and 3-7-8 adds a number, so they match. Carrying on like this (I could add the full thought process here, but it was pretty straightforward) gives each triangular symbol a code, and the letter for each pair goes on the image at their intersection (shown in the image below).

### Image

> Circling each item in and adding each letter to the image gives us the following:
>  [image: image with items found and letters added]

### Final Answer

> Replacing each symbol along the top with the letter its corresponding item is closest to and adding spaces where necessary gives "Lewis and Paula are cool." This message is for the "two people in particular [that] come to [your] Codes and Ciphers Club almost every week."

Comment: Great job, would you like a hint?

Comment: @JoshuaBizley Sure, I'd take a hint! This looks like a super cool puzzle, but I'm completely at a loss on how to proceed

Comment: Been a while since I have used this site so can't remember how to use spoilers in comments so have put a hint in the post; let me know if and when you would like another.

Comment: @JoshuaBizley I added my final answer; this was super satisfying to finish!